# Quantum Mechanics/Physics Textbook

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

This is a reasonably common question however most threads seemed to be focused on introduction to the subject only.

I am looking for a textbook in quantum mechanics/physics so that I can revise before starting my PhD. I have Quantum Mechanics by Mandl and have read the Griffiths textbook which seems to get good praise but I don't feel convinced by it.

A book that goes from elementary quantum mechanics to masters level would be ideal. I understand this is something subjective but any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: IMO, use whatever the grad course offered at your program uses.

Comment: Wouldn't a better home for this be *chat*?  It's a fact that this isn't a conceptual physics question and this (the main site) is not a physics forum.

Comment: @Alfred Centauri: Probably _opinion-based_ also.

Comment: You have an entire physics library at your school... go in and take a look at the quantum physics section.

Comment: @CuriousOne the library! Of course! Why did I not see that before...obviously I have looked at many books, I was looking for a concensus. Not a statement in the obvious.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos yes I reviewed my MPhys course lecture notes, but I was also after a text that I could refer to. My lecturer seems to think the one stop shop is Feynman Volume III. So I will read those.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin: The books have to fit your needs, not the needs of an imaginary average of people on this site. Isn't that logical?

Comment: @CuriousOne Of course, I noted that textbook preferences are of course subjective - however having some suggestions from people who are at a similar level is a reasonable place to start in my view. Exploring every single text on QM is not practical.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin: How do you know which level the people are on that are giving the recommendations? As for finding books that suit me... that's a ten minute affair. I look at a dozen pages and then I know if I can handle the book, or not. It's not rocket science. More importantly, I know that the book exists and if I want to up my game, I can just get it, again.

Comment: @CuriousOne Right after this I feel we should agree to disagree, because my question has been answered and nothing more has been added. I specified the level I was aiming for in my question. Personally, I don't feel flicking through a book lets you get a good feel for the text. If it does for you, great; it does not for me.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin: You don't feel like flicking trough a book for a few minutes but you are willing to spend half a year of working trough one that someone else has "recommended" for you? And, of course, you will not look at any books that have not been recommended, ever. OK. That's just about the entire science library, then. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R. Shankar's book is a really good transitory book between Griffiths and Sakurai (commonly used in grad. schools) as it begins by building up a solid linear algebra foundation, doesn't shy away from Dirac notation (something that Griffiths annoyingly does), and begins to delve into the group theoretical aspects of the subject. If you feel comfortable enough with Shankar, then I'd suggest you go straight to Sakurai. I'd also recommend picking up Dirac's book, both because it ensures that you understand the foundations well and also for its poetry.

Answer (score 2):

Zettili is good with a lot of worked examples. And can be a starting point.

Bransden & Joachain could be something you want to look at